# How to post (insert) a video to youtube with token?

Tags: android, post, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to upload a video to youtube.In IOS i did this.

But in android I don't know how can i do this.

**I have token.**

Anyone help me with sample code please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a demo project here

https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android

Or sample code here

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video

Comment: I just need to post request with token